# Alpha not showing up in renders for textures painted with transparent png

Tags: rendering, transparency, texture-painting

I want to paint the fassade of my building with some leaves here and there. The file I'm using as a brush is a png with transparent parts. It's working fine in texture paint mode, but in renders it always displays the alpha as black. I created the picture which is painted on with transparent background though, so I'm not seeing why this is happening. Any clues?

[image]

Comment: How does your shader network look like? Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @brockmann's hint I was able to resolve this issue. It was just a matter of connecting the alpha channel of the image node (got to shading tab) to the alpha input of the material node as such:

**before:**

[image]

**after:**

[image]

Apparently Evee does not render this correctly, so I needed to switch to cycles to see how it looks!

Comment: Works with Eevee as well: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3eec.jpg